# Why doesn't "n" downgrade my node version on a Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, n

I’m using Mac Big Sur.  I want to downgrade the version of Node.  I tried the below (installing without sudo gives me permission errors) …

```
$ sudo n 14.15.1
   installed : v14.15.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v14.17.6 at /usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node
```

But I still get the current version when I check

```
$ node -v
v14.17.6
```

Fwiw, here’s what I see with “which node”

```
$ which node
/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node
```

**Edit:** My $PATH when I run 'echo $PATH' ...

```
/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@global/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:/Users/davea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/bin
```

**Edit 2:** PATH vars for both regular user and sudo user ...

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@global/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/Users/davea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/bin

$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@global/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin:/Users/davea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.cabal/bin:/Users/davea/.ghcup/bin:/Users/davea/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: did you install n globally or with brew?

Comment: Ooh, I don't remember.  "which n" reveals /usr/local/bin/n is that helps.

Comment: You have removed /usr/local/opt/node@14 from PATH so hopefully fixed original problem, but now have added nvm so still got multiple nodes in PATH with /Users/davea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n` message is telling you that the version it just "installed" and the version that is "active" are different. You have two versions of node installed, and the active version is the one that is first in the `PATH`.

The active version is `/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin/node`. I don't recognise that path, not sure what was used to install that. It must be in your `PATH` variable and there might be a clue in your login script as to what added `/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin` to the `PATH`?

To get the `n` installed version of node to be the active version, you could delete the other copy of node, or put `/usr/local/bin` earlier in `PATH` so it is found first, or simplest remove `/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin` from your PATH variable.

Comment: Added output of my $PATH to my question.

Comment: @dave Something put /usr/local/opt/node@14/bin into your PATH. Have look in your shell startup script for what did that, and remove it since you want to be able to switch node versions using n. I will update my answer a little.

Comment: There was a line in my "~/.bash_profile" that read "export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"".  I removed that, spawned a new shell, but the problem remains.

Comment: What is your PATH now? Check using "env" and "sudo env". By default sudo does not use the same environment variables as your current shell, so potential for differences there to add to the confusion!

Comment: I do see a "/Users/davea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin" creeping in for both the sudo $PATH and regular user $PATH but I don't see a reference to this directory in either my ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile or /etc/profile files.

Comment: The nvm directory has been added to your PATH by installing and using nvm. You mentioned trying nvm in another comment. To uninstall nvm see https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#uninstalling--removal